# Tensorflow CNN model incompatible shape error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, conv-neural-network

I have an array with a shape of [274 documents, 439 equal length sentences per document, 384-dimensional sbert embeddings per sentence].  I'm trying to fit a CNN model that predicts a binary value per document.

Below is the model architecture:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(274, 384, input_length=439)
sequence_input = Input(shape=(439,))
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

# first conv filter
embedded_sequences = Reshape((439, 384, 1))(embedded_sequences)
x = Conv2D(100, (5, 384), activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
x = MaxPooling2D((439 - 5 + 1, 1))(x)

# second conv filter
y = Conv2D(100, (4, 384), activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
y = MaxPooling2D((439 - 4 + 1, 1))(y)

# third conv filter
z = Conv2D(100, (3, 384), activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
z = MaxPooling2D((439 - 3 + 1, 1))(z)

# concatenate the convolutional layers
alpha = concatenate([x,y,z])

# flatten the concatenated values
alpha = Flatten()(alpha)

# add dropout
alpha = Dropout(0.5)(alpha)

# make predictions
preds = Dense(274, activation='softmax')(alpha)

# build model
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
adadelta = optimizers.Adadelta()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adadelta,
              metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(x=X_train_sent_emb_3m, y=y_train_sent_emb_3m, epochs=25 , validation_data=(X_test_sent_emb_3m, y_test_sent_emb_3m))
```

The model compiles but when I run the fit call I'm getting the following error message:

Epoch 1/25
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 439) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 439), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_15'), name='input_15', description="created by layer 'input_15'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 439, 384).
...
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [439, 384, 384], output_shape = [439, 384, 1]

Any suggestions on what I need to change to make the model work for the shape of the data?

Comment: does changing `sequence_input = Input(shape=(439,))` to `sequence_input = Input(shape=(439,384))` help?

Comment: when I update the shape of Input to (439, 384), I get the following error message: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [439, 384, 384], output_shape = [439, 384, 1]

Comment: I updated the shape of embedded sequences to (439,384,384) as follows:

embedded_sequences = Reshape((439, 384, 384))(embedded_sequences)

the model now compiles but when I run model.fit I get the following error message:

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 274) are incompatible